# getting android source by repo

Tags: android, repository

I'm trying to get the android source code. When I run:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest<br/>
```

I got the following error:

> Get https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo
>   error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 502
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JBQ](https://groups.google.com/group/android-building/browse_thread/thread/981aa27ee819ca42):

> Occasionally a server gets itself in a bad state, and normally detects 
>   it and restarts itself. When you see a 403 or a 503, wait a little bit 
>   (say, half an hour), and retry.
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience. the team working on googlesource.com is 
>   tracking down those issues.

I'd try again in a bit and see if it succeeds. If not, you might consider joining that Google Group and inquiring there.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a VM to get the source code? I was having the same issues (been trying to get ICS source for 4+ hours with these issues) and I'm using virtualbox. In the VM window I went to devices->network adapters and changed the adapter type from NAT to bridged, the issue is now completely solved.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use github mirror. Also there you can download entire repo as a zipped file, without using git directly (and faster btw).

https://github.com/android